# Elements shifting to left even with float-right

Tags: html, css

Please look into this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/794ghazr/5/) code.

Elements in right columns are incrementally shifting to left, even though I've used `float-right`.

I wanted the right column to be aligned to right border, just as the first value under Jenkins.

Please suggest what am I missing.

*Thank You*

Comment: For start - don't use line breaks `<br>` for styling. Use <p> or <div> instead of <span><br>

Comment: Change` padding-bottom: 30px` to `padding-bottom: 40px`. The 0 in Other and None are cut off.

Comment: `even though I've used float-right` --   I can not see any  `float: right;` I see  `float: left;` ??

Comment: _Please_ don't just link to a JS fiddle. Please attach the code to the question. Also, what are you trying to get the end result to look like? I'm having trouble determining what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Jhecht, Noted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please remove the float-right from a tags of "metrics-content-t2" div and use text-align right.

```css
.metric-div-row {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.metric-div-row>div {
  flex: 1;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  /* Adding Border  */
  border-radius: 12px;
  border: 2px solid cadetblue;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  background-color: white;
}

.all-project-heading {
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: darkslategray;
}

.metrics-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
}

.metrics-content-t1 {
  float: left;
}

.metrics-content-t2 {
  float: right;
  text-align:right;
}

.metrics-heading {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.metrics-value-small {
  color: #119bc9;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.floatRight {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="metric-div-row">
  <div class="metric-divs">
    <div class="all-project-heading">
      CI Statistics
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="metrics-content">
      <div class="metrics-content-t1">
        <span class="metrics-heading">Deployer</span>
        <br/>
        <a id="ciDeployerCount" class="metrics-value-small">0</a>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <span class="metrics-heading">GoCD</span>
        <br/>
        <a id="ciGocdCount" class="metrics-value-small">0</a>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <span class="metrics-heading">Other</span>
        <br/>
        <a id="ciOtherCount" class="metrics-value-small">0</a>
      </div>
      <div class="metrics-content-t2">
        <span class="metrics-heading">Jenkins</span>
        <br/>
        <a id="ciJenkinsCount" class="metrics-value-small">0</a>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <span class="metrics-heading">TFS</span>
        <br/>
        <a id="ciTfsCount" class="metrics-value-small">0</a>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <span class="metrics-heading">None</span>
        <br/>
        <a id="ciNoneCount" class="metrics-value-small">0</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

In this case you may probably want to use `text-align: right` in the parent div instead of a float on the elements themselves. Float is not typically used for aligning content, but for aligning the containers of that content. It's often used for layouts. Text-align makes more sense here, because you want to align text.